# Can I restrict at runtime which folders I'm allowed in within a CGI script?

Tags: linux, security, cgi, sandbox

I'm writing cgi programs for my websites (all hosted with a single lighttpd service). The programs read directories and files in subfolders of where they each reside. They run using the webserver's user id.

I'd like to ensure that no screw up happens that could lead to my programs reading outside their intended workspace. I imagine adding a line somewhere at runtime near the top of my cgi programs that goes like:

```
restrict_io(".");
```

anything after that line would get access errors if they do something funky like trying to run arbitrary things from /usr/bin or opening files in ../other_website/stuff.

Any easy solution out there? I skimmed over various solutions but they all seem like they need a lot of investment of my part just to understand if they can actually do what I want.

chroot(2) doc says "it is not intended to  be  used  for any kind of security purpose, neither to fully sandbox a process nor to restrict filesystem system calls" It also needs capabilities or root, which the web user doesn't have. It also might be over-complicated, as I suspect you need to prepare the new "/" carefully.

seccomp(2) doc is pretty long and tedious to read. It sounds like it does a lot, but it's unclear if it can do what I want.

pledge(2) is BSD only, and my server is a flavor of Linux, and I want to keep it that way because I'm using that machine for more than web hosting. Then again, I'm not sure pledge does what I want either.

LXC, haven't read about it yet.

Docker looks like a product from some company. I haven't read if it's free, open-source.

If you haven't read between the lines yet, a C solution would be best, but if not C don't hesitate to contribute an answer too. A code snippet is worth a thousand words.

Answer (score 0):

I found that AppArmor (part of the linux kernel) does exactly what I want.

You call aa_change_profile(const char * profile) in your code.
The profile is first registered with the CLI util apparmor_parser, as root.
You might need to enable apparmor with kernel parameters though, and start the service:

```
linux ... apparmor=1 security=apparmor
```

> sudo systemctl enable apparmor

Example cgi.armor:

```
profile restricted_cgi {
  deny network,
  /home/pi/website1/** r,
}
```

> sudo apparmor_parser -a cgi.armor

Example my_program.c compiled with -lapparmor:

```
#include <sys/apparmor.h>
...
int armor = aa_change_profile("restricted_cgi");
if(armor) {
  printf("Armor error: %s\n", strerror(errno));
  return 1;
}
```